# I never Programmed before, What Language Should I Learn?

Tags: objective-c, programming-languages

I'm an engineer by profession, and my work requires some cost estimating.

What I want to do is buld a cost estimating program where I drag a module from a library, say a water filter, drag an ozonator, and drag a chlorine contact tank, and then connect them.

what I want to do is for this program to ask for a few design parameters for the modules I add, and then calculate a cost.

Ideally I want the application to contact a sever and ask for current costs for things

and super duper ideally, I would like to be able to add the ability to track water quality paramers across each module. What I mean by this is say I'm intrested in pH, and I know how pH changes with an ozonator, I want it to take pH information from before the ozonator, and spit out a number after the ozonator, based equations on how pH changes with ozonation..

This would require water quality paramters to be embedded in the "connections" etc.

I think it would be fun to make it an ipad app, so I was thinking objective C, but the primary use would probably be a windows machine, also would it be easy to make it look for cost data on a server? alternitavely, if it could be a web application that could be accesed from the company website securely, that would work too.

lastly if it could generate a drawing based on the modules you drag, with dimensions, maybe render it in 3d would be double plus good, but that's not within the current scope

so, I ask, What language should I learn to do this?

your help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're talking about seems like a very large project even for someone who knows programming well.

If the primary use is going to be on a windows machine (not on an ipad), then objective C won't help much.  If you want to build a web application (which seems like a natural fit), I suggest some web framework in the backend.  For this you can choose between languages/frameworks like Python, Ruby/Rails, Php.

I could go into each feature you discuss, but each one could take months for a really solid integration.  It sounds like a full SAAS company.

My suggestion would be to simplify it down a whole lot.  Would it be possible for the first prototype to be a text-based application?  For example, a simple calculator where you enter some parameters for the modules you want, and it outputs the sum cost of them.  That could be a good starting point.

If you can hire software engineers to help, then it would be much more feasible.

Comment: Currently the the modules exist as excel spreadsheets add ins so a text based solution would be a step sideways in some regards, unless it was online and had more security. It's a large project but the modules are built in excel so at least that part is done. My company has been building this for 10 years now, but they want to take it off excel and to the next level. I guess in order to simplify the scope a new question would be: what language would be best to build a proof of concept module that connects to a database for current cost data, and is somewhat visual

Comment: That narrows it down, but it's still a very open ended question.  If you can export the necessary data as .csv files (especially if the equations aren't too important), it may be possible to import the data pretty easily into a database with a python or ruby script.  SQLLite is a pretty good choice for a local solution (not web).  Any popular language can be "somewhat" visual... I'd have to have a better understanding of the mock-ups before suggesting anything there.

Comment: Let's see if I can explain it better. For the proof of concept I want to model a concrete tank. I want to drag a gray box from a " library" to the workspace, have a a way for the user to input length, width height and wall thickness, then have the program calculate the volume of concrete required, then have the application go to the database and pull out the cost per cubic yard, and tell the user it's going to cost x amount in concrete. And then the user can drag another gray box' type in inputs, and get a grand total for two concrete tanks